# Python How To Square Sin For The Height Equation

Tags: python, math, trigonometry, physics

In python math im trying to work out how high an object would be and I need to square sin to do. The equation is velocity^ * sin^(angle) / 2 * gravity.

```
v = float(input('start vlocity m/s: '))
a = float(input('start angle : '))
equ = ((v**2) * math.sin**2(math.radians(a)) / 2 * 9.81
print(str(equ) + ' M')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I'd write it:

```
v = float(input('start vlocity m/s: '))
a = float(input('start angle : '))
p = v*math.sin(math.radians(a))
g = 9.81
equ = p*p/(2*g)  
print(str(equ) + ' M')
```

Check that denominator - shouldn't it be dividing by 2*g?

Comment: Yes, the units don't work out if `g` isn't in the denominator (which won't happen without the parens).  But you want to square `p`, not `a`.

Comment: Stupid me - going too fast.  Thank you for the correction - sharp eyes.

Comment: only one thing thank you but the velocity at the start needs to be squared

Comment: What do you mean?  I did square the velocity.  To be precise, I squared the y-component of the velocity, because I multiplied it by the sine of the angle first.

Answer (score 6):

sin^2(x) is the same (mathematically) as (sin(x))^2, so you can write

```
equ = ((v**2) * math.pow(math.sin(math.radians(a)), 2) / 2 * 9.81
```

Or

```
equ = ((v**2) * math.sin(math.radians(a))**2 / 2 * 9.81
```

Comment: @inspectorG4dget -- But isn't it nice now that you have more than 10K rep you can see how often that happens to the rest of us :-).